# Display the next record in a session php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I'm trying to output results in a session variable which has been populated from a SQL Query using `echo current` and `echo next`. However no text is echoed to screen.

SQL Statement used to get data and put into array

```
$SQL = "Select * from Property_Features WHERE pf_pr_ID = 3";
$result = $conn->query($SQL);
$_SESSION[arrProperty_Features] = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Attempt to echo first item in the array (current)

```
<p><input class="w3-input" name="txtFeature1" type="text" 
id="txtFeature1" value="<?php echo current 
($_SESSION[arrProperty_Features][pf_Feature]);?>"><br>
```

Attempt to echo second item in array (next)

```
<p><input class="w3-input" name="txtFeature2" type="text" 
id="txtFeature2" value="<?php echo next 
($_SESSION[arrProperty_Features][pf_Feature]);?>"><br>
```

Comment: "$result->fetch_assoc()" Wont give you all the result at once. Keep iterating over it until it gives you null

Comment: Thanks Tarun - I've tried this but it's seems to be stuck in an eternal loop

while($result = $conn->query($SQL)){
 $_SESSION[arrProperty_Features] = $result->fetch_assoc();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code i think you will get desired result. php current or next function working on single array not multidimensional array.through fetch_assoc() you wil get multidimensional array.

```
<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['arrProperty_Features'][] = $row;
    }

    ?>
    <!--Attempt to echo first item in the array-->
    <p><input class="w3-input" name="txtFeature1" type="text" id="txtFeature1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['arrProperty_Features'][0]['pf_Feature'];?>"><br>

    <!--Attempt to echo second item in the array !-->
    <p><input class="w3-input" name="txtFeature1" type="text" id="txtFeature2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['arrProperty_Features'][1]['pf_Feature'];?>"><br>
```